# Is there any way to open constraint dictionaries at compile-time in GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following Haskell code (GHC 8.2):

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
import Data.Constraint

type family Head xs where
  Head (x ': xs) = x

type family Tail xs where
  Tail (x ': xs) = xs

class IsList xs where
  isList :: (xs ~ '[] => r) -> ((xs ~ (Head xs ': Tail xs), IsList (Tail xs)) => r) -> r

instance IsList '[] where isList r _ = r
instance IsList xs => IsList (x ': xs) where isList _ r = r

type family Prepend xs ys where
  Prepend '[] ys = ys
  Prepend (x ': xs) ys = x ': Prepend xs ys

prependPreservesIsList :: forall xs ys. (IsList xs, IsList ys) => Dict (IsList (Prepend xs ys))
prependPreservesIsList = isList @xs Dict (withDict (prependPreservesIsList @(Tail xs) @ys) Dict)

class IsList (Deps a) => Hard (a :: *) where
  type Deps a :: [*]

instance (Hard a, Hard b) => Hard (Either a b) where
  type Deps (Either a b) = Prepend (Deps a) (Deps b)
```

it fails with

```
Main.hs:37:10: error:
    • Could not deduce (IsList (Prepend (Deps a) (Deps b)))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: (Hard a, Hard b)
        bound by the instance declaration at Main.hs:37:10-46
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Hard (Either a b)’
   |
37 | instance (Hard a, Hard b) => Hard (Either a b) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What the code is trying to do is construct a class `Hard` that has an associated list of types `Deps`, where the `Deps` corresponding to an `Either a b` are supposed to be the concatenation of the `Deps` corresponding to `a` and `b`.

We know how to prove to GHC that this form of concatenation preserves the `IsList` class, as witnessed by `prependPreservesIsList`. If we had `(Hard a, Hard b)` and we needed to write normal code that required `(IsList (Deps (Either a b)))` we'd just `withDict prependPreservesIsList` and be on our way. But we need GHC to recognize this constraint "at compile time", in order to grant that the `Either a b` instance is legal.

Is there any way to "open a constraint dictionary" at compile-time, or to otherwise finagle this code so as to cause GHC to accept the `Either a b` instance?

Comment: May I ask why you're using an eliminator rather than a more conventional GADT as evidence?

Answer (score 2):

Consider switching from type-level lists to type-level trees. So:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

data Tree a = Empty | Node a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)

class IsTree xs where
    isTree ::
        (xs ~ 'Empty => a) ->
        (forall x. xs ~ 'Node x => a) ->
        (forall l r. (xs ~ 'Branch l r, IsTree l, IsTree r) => a) ->
        a

instance IsTree 'Empty where isTree a _ _ = a
instance IsTree ('Node x) where isTree _ a _ = a
instance (IsTree l, IsTree r) => IsTree ('Branch l r) where isTree _ _ a = a

class IsTree (Deps a) => Hard a where
    type Deps a :: Tree *

instance (Hard a, Hard b) => Hard (Either a b) where
    type Deps (Either a b) = 'Branch (Deps a) (Deps b)
```

Comment: Nice end run around computation!

Comment: Neat! This is a clever idea that works around the problem in this specific example, and I learned something from it (Thanks!), but it doesn't answer my more general question as to whether there's any way to argue to GHC that it should accept an instance via some kind of dictionary pushing. (I'm assuming the answer here is just "no".)

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to represent type class constraints, as first class dictionaries (`Dict`), although it's not nearly as ergonomic:

```
class Hard a where
  type Deps a :: [*]
  depsIsList :: Dict (IsList (Deps a))

instance (Hard a, Hard b) => Hard (Either a b) where
  type Deps (Either a b) = Prepend (Deps a) (Deps b)
  depsIsList =
   case depsIsList @a of
     Dict ->
       case depsIsList @b of
         Dict -> prependPreservesIsList @(Deps a) @(Deps b)
```

Using `(:-)` from the *constraints* package might make composing dictionaries like that a tiny bit less painful.

Comment: I'm familiar with various ways to propagate the necessary constraints "at runtime" (eg via Dict, or via replacing classes with datatypes entirely); I was hoping for some method to use something like an `:-` to convince GHC that a certain instance is legal.